# Get random array value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a mock dataset to test some queries on. How would I get a random selection from an array in mysql. For example:

```
select id, random(['microsoft', 'chrome', 'firefox']) browser from mytable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `elt()` and `random()`:

```
select id,
       elt(floor(rand() * 3 + 1), 'microsoft', 'chrome', 'firefox') browser
from mytable;
```

Comment: @David542: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

Comment: @David542 . . . It chooses a value from a list.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks -- what does "ELT" stand for? (not extract-load-transform, is it?)

Comment: @David542 . . . My guess would be "element".